# Rails gem for using routes inside of the article body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

is there any gem allowing to replace string in particular format for links to some controller with parameters?

Example: In the content of article /articles/2/second-article I want to link to a previous article /articles/1/first-article.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I have written a helper for that:

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def raw_with_links(text)

    text.gsub! /{'(.+?)', (.+?)(,(.+?))*}/ do |full_match|
      # The expression returned from this block will be used as the replacement string
      # $1 will be the matched content between the ' and ' quotes.
      # $2 will be the mathed content in the second group with the route name
      #4 will be the matched content in the last group with route parameters, if any

      url = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.send $2, $4
      link = "<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + $1 + "</a>"

    end

    raw(text)

  end

end
```

then you can call it in a view like this:

```
<%= raw_with_links @article.content %>
```

and here is how to create a link in the text (the route parameter (value 7 in the example bellow) is not mandatory):

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @article.content = "<p>This is the article content with the {'link', other_route_name_path, 7} to the other route.</p>"
  end

end
```

and the result is (considering the route `other_route_name` is `other_route/:id`:

```
<p>This is the article content with the <a href="other_route/7">link</a> to the other route.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not a "gem" but you can do this easily in your model.

```
class Article

  def next
    self.class.where("id > ?", id).first
  end
  def previous
    self.class.where("id < ?", id).last
  end

end
```

Then you can use these in your controller:

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@next_article = @article.next
@previous_article = @article.previous
```

Comment: Ok, but the purpose is not to create a "previous" and "next" links, but to have a possibility to link also to another controllers and without any sequence. So once link to *article/7* and next time to *news/1982*

Comment: Is the next item random or is there a method to your madness? Do you have some logic that will determine where the link will go, otherwise you would just create a direct `link_to` to related item.

Comment: But I cannot use `link_to` in the string field loaded from db, right?

Comment: No. But If you post some of the code you are using, we may be able to guide you through doing what you are asking. Right now it seems a little confusing without seeing what you are doing

Comment: Ok `@model = Article.find(7)` and inside `@model.ArticleContent` (so it is the field loaded from db) there is a link to some other controller action.
Never mind, I wrote my own helper, see my next answer.